Showing $\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{2k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}=2^{n}\binom{2n}{n}$, and another identity, combinatorially
By comparing different explicit formulas for the Gauss hypergeometric functions
$$
{}_2F_1\biggl(-\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}-n;z\biggr)
\quad\text{and}\quad
{}_2F_1\biggl(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},1-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2}-n;z^2\biggr)
$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$, I obtained the following two identities
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{2k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}=2^{n}\binom{2n}{n}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}_0
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation}\label{ID-n-Factorial2sums}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2^{k}}{k!}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{2^j}\frac{(2k-2j-1)!!}{(n-j)!}\binom{2k-j-1}{j-1}
=\frac{1}{n!}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}_0.
\end{equation}
Are there direct or combinatorial proofs of these two combinatorial identities?

In this forum you're expected to show your own work in order to get help.

@jjagmath is right. Please tell us where they come from, and most importantly, if they are supposed to be related or not.

Answer for the first identity only.
According to Gould's table of identites eq.(1.64), we have a even stronger statement for the first identity
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \binom nj\binom j{k-j}2^{2j} = 2^k\binom{2n}{k},
$$
which is probably easier to prove. From the hint he gives, I came up with the plan of expanding $(x+1)^{2n} = (x^2 + 2x + 1)^n$ and identify coefficients. Of course the coefficient of the first identity is $\binom{2n}{k}$. For the second, we'll a need a double expansion
\begin{align}
(x^2 + 2x + 1)^n
&= \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} (x^2+2x)^j \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} x^{2k} (2x)^{j-k} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{n}{j}  \binom{j}{k} 2^{j-k} x^{j+k} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=j}^{2j} \binom{n}{j}  \binom{j}{k-j} 2^{2j-k} x^k \\
&= \sum_{0\leq k\leq2j\leq2n} \binom{n}{j}  \binom{j}{k-j} 2^{2j-k} x^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2n} x^k \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}  \binom{j}{k-j} 2^{2j-k}
\end{align}
which is the coefficient we were looking for.
